# SFML - C++ - Рисование фигуры из класса

Tags: c++, sfml

Не могу нарисовать фигуру, которую создал в классе. У меня есть функция Main и класс Player. В функции Main всё по стандарту - рисуется окно, появляется цикл, в котором clear, draw и display. 
И в своём классе Player я создал метод draw(), который должен рисовать Круг по заданным мною параметром, а потом возвращать её, чтобы в главной функции window.draw() мог принять этот круг и вывести его на экран.
Какой должен быть тип данных метода draw() в классе Player, если у круга тип sf::CircleShape?

Answer (score 1):

```
class player
{

  public:

    sf::CircleShape draw(int r)
    {
      return sf::CircleShape(r);
    }

};

int main()
{

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(300, 300), "1");

    ...

    player p;
    window.draw(p.draw(15));
    window.display();

    ...
}
```

Таким и должен быть, может нарисовали после `window.display()`? Или `window.clear()` например после `window.draw()`.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался.
Проблема была в том, что файл .h требовал у меня подключить библиотеку sfml, чего я никак не ожидал. После подключения проблема ушла!

Answer (score 0):

Я подключил библиотеки SFML Graphics в файл .h моего класса - и всё заработало.
В файле .cpp уже были подключены данные библиотеки, если что.